# Is it a bad idea to acquire a lock in a destructor?

Tags: c++, synchronization, raii

Say we have something along the lines of the following pseudocode, with the goal of achieving both concurrency and taking advantage of RAII:

```
class Foo {
public:
    vector<int> nums;
    mutex lock;
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(Foo &foo) : m_foo(foo) 
    {
        lock_guard<mutex>(foo.lock);
        m_num = foo.nums.back();
        foo.nums.pop_back();
    }
    ~Bar()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex>(foo.lock);
        foo.nums.push_back(m_num);
    }
private:
    Foo &m_foo;
    int m_num;
};
```

Then, say we may have any number of instances of Bar, with the idea being that when they go out of scope, the destructor will return their held "resource" to the controller Foo class. However, we also need to ensure thread safety, hence the locks. I'm a little wary of this design, however, since taking a mutex in a destructor seems like a bad idea intuitively. Am I overthinking things, or if not, is there a better way to take advantage of RAII here?

Comment: It's not bad, but I can't say the same about the code design. If `Foo` owns  critical data, has `mutex lock;`, then it should care of guarded data access.

Comment: Acquiring a lock in destructor is no different than acquiring a lock in any other function.

Comment: (But make sure to catch the possible exceptions directly in the destructor; if the destructor is called during stack unwinding from another exception, and it in-turn throws an additional exception when trying to lock a mutex, the program will terminate irrecoverably)

Comment: If you refactored your design so that foo had mutexed operations to pop and push, instead of having everything public, your question would sort itself out.

Comment: @Taekahn I don't think it wouldn't sort itself out, unless I'm misunderstanding the intention behind the question. The pop operation would still be called in the destructor, and that would still lock a mutex. The concerns with locking a mutex in a destructor do not disappear by simply moving the mutex lock to another function to be called by the destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with locking a mutex in a destructor. For instance, shared resources might need to be made thread-safe. Releasing ownership of a shared resource, then, might require locking a mutex. If RAII just fell apart in multithreaded programming, it wouldn't be a very useful tool. Indeed, access to a `std::shared_ptr`'s control block is thread safe, including when decrementing the reference counter during the shared pointer's destruction. Apparently this is usually implemented with atomic operations rather than a mutex lock (don't quote me on this), but the context is the same: you're releasing ownership of a shared resource during destruction, and that has to be recorded in a thread-safe way.

However, keep in mind: locking a mutex can throw an exception, and you should (almost) always absorb exceptions in destructors with try/catch. Otherwise, if the stack is already unwinding due to another exception, the program will terminate immediately and irrecoverably, regardless of whether the calling code is equipped to absorb the original exception and / or the destructor's exception.

But there might be a way to restructure your code to avoid the issue entirely: A `Bar` doesn't actually *need* a reference to a `Foo`; it only needs an `int`. In your code, the `Bar` requests an `int` from a given `Foo`. When the `Bar` is destroyed, it needs to give the `int` back to the `Foo` so that it can be recycled; this requires storing an internal reference to the `Foo` throughout its lifetime so that it can communicate with it during destruction. **Instead**, consider giving the `int` to the `Bar` directly upon construction, and taking the `int` away from it upon destruction. This is the driving principle behind [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which constitutes the 'D' in "SOILD". Consequently, it brings with it all of the typical advantages of dependency injection (e.g., improving testability of the `Bar` class).

For instance, this logic could be tracked in a larger class which manages a `Foo` object along with all of its associated `Bar` objects. Here's some pseudocode, but the exact interface details will depend on your application:

```
class BarPool:
    Foo foo;
    Map<int, Bar> bars;
    mutex m;

    BarPool(Foo foo) : foo(foo) {}

    int add_bar():
        lock m;
        // Note: foo.pop() should probably be made thread-safe
        // by internally locking / unlocking foo's mutex
        int i = foo.pop()
        bars.add(i, new Bar(i));
        unlock m;
        return i

    void remove_bar(int i):
        lock m;
        // foo.push() should also probably be made thread-safe
        bars.remove(i)
        foo.push(i)
        unlock m;

    ...
```

Comment: Another advantage of this design is that a `Bar` object doesn't *have* to receive its `int` from a `Foo` object; it can receive it from *anywhere*. If you decide that you want to have a set of `Bar` objects which receive their `int`s from a `Baz` object instead, you can write a separate class which does that. You could further describe an interface for `IntCollection` objects, implemented by `Foo` and `Baz`. Then a `BarPool` would only depend on an abstract `IntCollection` interface, which is further in-line with the dependency injection principle.